# Import 3rd party framework into Swift Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been looking everywhere and trying everything but I can't get this to work. I'm trying to create a Cocoa Touch Framework (in Swift) to share code between an iOS app I'm developing and its extension. All of the shared code relies on the [`NMSSH`](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH) framework. I added the NMSSH framework to my framework, made sure it showed up in "Link Binary with Libraries" and that it was targeted at my framework. However, when I add `#import <NMSSH/NMSSH.h>` to my umbrella header, I get the error `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyFramework'`.

In most of the places I have looked, they say the fix to this is to import the 3rd party framework in a .m file in my framework. The problem is that my framework is in Swift and thus doesn't have any .m files. I tried adding `import NMSSH` to my .swift file, but that just results in `No such module 'NMSSH'`.

There must be a way to actually get this to work without rewriting all of my code in Objective-C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)

Comment: Common Crypto is not 3rd party though. I tried that but it's still not working

Comment: What there ever an answer to this?

Comment: Hi @Garrett, did you find a solution for this? I have a similar problem when I want to use DropboxSDK framework in my Cocoa Touch Framework.