# Using CommonCrypto in Swift generates not safe for use in extensions warning

Tags: ios, macos, swift, ios-frameworks, commoncrypto

I've created a simple lib to use HMAC digest for Swift called *"[SweetHMAC](http://jancassio.github.io/SweetHMAC/)"*. This lib is so simple, basically is a wrapper to CommonHMAC.h in Swift.

I can build and deploy any iOS project using SweetHMAC correctly but, seems by some security issue, my approach is not safe. There is the warning I receive after run the iOS tests for example.

`warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions`

This code is not safe enough to put in iOS AppStore, and the app can be rejected by that. For OSX, there is no problems.

I know, there are HMAC ports for Swift, but my challenge is to try to enable Swift to use CommonCrypto safely.

I have implemented this project using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189873/457569) and works fine!

My question is, how possible is to create and use use modules like CommonCrypto in Swift frameworks safely for iOS?

Comment: Provide the code you are using?

Comment: @Zaph the source code link was added in my question, check out the link for SweetHMAC please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation from Apple, the suggestion for said error is to make sure that the option of using "Require Only App-Extension-Safe API" is checked.

> To configure an app extension target to use an embedded framework, set the target’s “Require Only App-Extension-Safe API” build setting to Yes. If you don’t, Xcode reminds you to do so by displaying the warning “linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions”.

[Here's the full documentation on extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

It is also worth noting that parts of the CommonCrypto API might not be available, as per [this discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6)

Comment: Thanks @Henri, I did this in [my library](http://jancassio.github.io/SweetHMAC/) a couple weeks ago and this fixed the problem. And yes, I forget to update my question with the solution, I think is fair enough to mark your answer as correct too. Thanks for advice.