# How to use a C dylib from a Swift file in a framework

Tags: c, xcode, swift, dylib

I'm looking at starting to use Swift in a framework, which uses `libz.dylib`, but it looks like there's no way to import it from within Swift. I tried `import zlib` and `import libz`, which didn't work. ZLib is already linked to the target.

It seems like the only way to get my Swift code to see the `zlib` classes is to import the necessary headers in a bridging header, but framework targets can't have a bridging header, so is there a way to use a dylib?

Comment: @rmaddy I included the objective-c tag as a workaround solution may involve Objective-C

Comment: Also check this answer [about integrating zilb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648121/native-zlib-inflate-deflate-for-swift3-on-ios)

Answer (score 11):

I have added a C/C++ dylib library, with C Public API headers to Swift Project.

Assume that the library is, libModule.dylib.

1. Create a Directory with "Module"

   ```
   mkdir Module; cd Module
   ```
2. Create a file module.map inside Module directory

   ```
   Touch module.map
   ```
3. create a directory, this will be the header files directory, any name will serve.

   ```
   mkdir Headers
   ```
4. copy all headers into Headers directory

   ```
   cp -R path/Headers Headers/
   ```
5. open module.map & copy below contents to it, Swift team suggest, adding prefix C in front of library name, in case if its a C library.

   ```
   module CModule {
     umbrella "Headers"  // for multiple files
     header "filename.h" // for single header file, in this case even the Header directory is not needed.
     export *
   }
   ```
6. Go to Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Search Paths
7. Add complete Module directory path to "Import Paths" key.
8. Go to Build Phases, Add New Copy Files Phase.
9. Drag libModule.dylib to the Copy Files phase. Select Destination to "Frameworks".
10. If required add the libModule.dylib to Link Binary With Libraries section of Build Phases.

If step 9 is missed, we get famous @rpath/ Image not found crash.

Now Import module in swift as below:

```
    import CModule // name given inside module.map
```

For system library, most steps don't require.. just create directory & module map file with correct header path and do 6, 7. 
Its seems step 10 not even required as its a system library.

```
    module CommonCrypto [system] {
      header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
      export *
    }
```

Comment: creating Headers directory is also optional, in that case the umbrella "Headers" becomes umbrella "." But copying all headers to root is something I won't consider.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks!

Comment: I wish I could thank you 100 times. Most complete answer ever!

Answer (score 1):

You can import system modules as described in this answer: [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)

**TLDR**

1. Add a Folder named `ZLib` to your framework directory
2. Add a `module.map` file with the following contents

`module ZLib [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h"
    export *
}`

You might have to change the **path to your zlib header**. The example works for  XCode 7 Beta and El Capitan.

3. Add the currently generated module.map file to your build settings
4. Import ZLib in your swift file and you will be ready to go

Comment: Thanks - that seems more like a workaround than a solution, though

Comment: Agree it should be easier to integrate modules, but it solves many other problems: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#problems-with-the-current-model