# Using an Objective-C .dylib in a Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, frameworks

I am trying to integrate an API for an eye tracking device into an app that I am currently writing in Swift.

The API is an Xcode project designed as a dylib that wraps a C++ project for the same thing. The git for this API can be found here:

https://github.com/EyeTribe/tet-objectivec-client

After a few tweaks to some of the linking flags, I was able to get the project to compile.

However, now I am lost as how I can use the .dylib in my Swift project.

I have tried adding it to the "Link Binary with Libraries" list, adding a bridging header file to include the public header file from the original project, etc.

I'm pretty stuck on this and am wondering what I am doing wrong.

I also tried adding a cocoa framework target to the objective c project but although the project would build, the actual framework file would be blank (I added the .m files for compile sources and the headers into the headers section).

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199010/how-to-use-a-c-dylib-from-a-swift-file-in-a-framework