# Native zlib inflate/deflate for Swift 3 on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, zlib

I'd like to be able to inflate/deflate Swift 3 data structs. I found [GzipSwift](https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift), but it's not clear how I make that available to my iOS app. The naive things I've tried include:

1. Copying the `Data+Gzip.swift` file into my own project. This then complains about the `import zlib` at the top of said file. I think that has something to do the with the modulemap files in the zlib directory of the same sources. But I'm not sure what or how to recreate those in my own project.
2. Cloned the repository from github, opened XCode and built in (pressed the run button basically). Then tried to add that as a linked library or framework to my own project. I'm pretty sure just selecting the top level directory of the repository is not what I want to do, but I didn't know what else to try.

I've found some other code out there, but it seems dated and relative to Swift 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just recently had to add that exact library and file to my project, and after a lot of troubleshooting finally got it working, so let me walk you through the steps!

Okay

1) Go to the top level directory of your project in finder, and create a new folder called `Swiftzlib` or whatever you want the name of the module that you will be importing to be. (What we will do is add the zlib library as a module, so think of it as importing Foundation or some such other module). To clarify, this `Swiftzlib` directory will end up as a child directory of the same directory that contains your `*.xcodeproj` and `*.xcworkspace` files.

2) Inside the folder you created, make two files.

- include.h
- module.modulemap

3) In your `include.h` file, enter the following:

```
#include<zlib.h>
```

4) In your `module.modulemap` file, enter the following:

```
module Swiftzlib [system] {
    header "include.h"
    export *
}
```

Where Swiftzlib is the same as the name of the folder that you created.

5) Open your Xcode project, and select your target

- 5a) In Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries, add `libz.tbd`
- 5b) In Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Search Paths, add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Swiftzlib` non-recursively to the import paths
- 5c) In Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags, add `-lz` as a flag

6) Select your project in Xcode (may not be necessary, but I've done it in my project and it works)

- 6a) In Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Search Paths, add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Swiftzlib` non-recursively to the import paths

7) In `Data+Gzip.swfit`, add `import Swiftzlib` to the top of the file

8) *Clean, Build, and Run!*

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detailed reply. I'll give it a try tomorrow and hopefully accept the answer then.

Comment: Sadly, I still get the "No such module Swiftzlib" error :(

Comment: Make sure that the path pointing to the library is correct, this is crucial.

Comment: Got it! My misunderstanding was in what constitutes the "top level directory of your project". In fact, maybe a lightbulb is coming on here... XCode tends to put all of the .swift sources in a project in a directory of the same name as the directory above it. Is this because that represents the intrinsic module for the project?

Comment: You could have placed the module anywhere within your projects file structure, you just would have had to choose the right path in the import section. As for your second question... I'm not sure. Xcode does this, even for obj-c projects so it could just be the file structure. I'm pretty sure with swift if files are in the same namespace (as in your project name) they can all be seen by the compiler without having to import them. You never import AppName as a module in your application.

Comment: i have followed all your steps but no luck...please guide me...in me Data_Gzip.swift it can't find Error and Data class

Comment: @HRaval that sounds like you're importing the Data+Gzip.swift class as the Swift 3 version in a non Swift 3 project

Comment: i am using swift 2.3

Comment: @HRaval right do you need to get the Swift 2.3 version of NSData+gzip instead of Data+Gzip

Comment: Thanx a lot.may you please provide me a link?

Comment: @HRaval https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift/releases/tag/2.0.0 here is the link to an older release

Comment: that is very useful!

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 5** implementation using **Compression**.

Took me a few days to realise I had to drop the first 2 bytes of the compressed data.
Hope it can help somebody else.

```
import Foundation
import Compression

func decompress(_ data: Data) -> String {
    let size = 8_000_000
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: size)
    let result = data.subdata(in: 2 ..< data.count).withUnsafeBytes ({
        let read = compression_decode_buffer(buffer, size, $0.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 1),
                                             data.count - 2, nil, COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
        return String(decoding: Data(bytes: buffer, count:read), as: UTF8.self)
    }) as String
    buffer.deallocate()
    return result
}
```

Comment: @The_Androctonus `size` is the allocating size for the buffer, that is, the amount of bytes reserved to be used. Usually a big number will do if you don't know how many bytes to expect when uncompressed.

Comment: It took me few days finding this same thing... Thanks for this answer.

Comment: i would have pulled my hair out figuring this one out! Thanks @vauxhall!

Comment: you saved my life! After days I finally come  across this answer. And I'm wondering why?

Comment: Incredible, thank you. This is now supported natively: [compressed(using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/3174960-compressed) and [decompressed(using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/3174961-decompressed)

Answer (score 4):

I maintain a small Swift 3+ wrapper around Apples native libcompression framework at:

https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression

Usage example for gzip:

```
let data: Data! = "https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt".data(using: .utf8)
let gzipped: Data! = data.zip()
let gunzipped: Data? = gzipped.unzip()
assert(data == gunzipped)
```

But if you are only interested in classic inflate and deflate you may use the `.inflate()` and `.deflate()` methods instead. That will save 18 bytes because the gzip header won't be added.

Comment: Pleasee add details from link here.

Comment: I still encounter the incorrect header check error using deflate()

Answer (score 0):

I made a small spm extension inspired by @vauxhall 's answer

https://github.com/mezhevikin/Zlib

```
import Zlib

// Decompressed data
print(data.decompressed)

// Decompressed string
print(data.decompressedString)
```