# Looking for Xcode Swift examples to decompress gzipped Json data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, gzip, zlib

I am trying to decompressed a Json data stream. I've found various decompression solutions, the native zlib seems easier, the other cocoa pod solutions produced new problems. The setting advised in [native zlib inflate/deflate for swift3 on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648121/native-zlib-inflate-deflate-for-swift3-on-ios) seems working, the problem is what's next. I've thoroughly searched the net, only found C or Obj-C example codes but not Swift's. Thanks.

Another solution I tried was with https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression. But I had problem trying to set it up according to the instruction so look into the short codes and took out the part that I think should work for me, hard-coded some of the options. But no matter which algorithm I tried, perform() return nil.

I also tried unzip(), it failed at guard header >> 8 & 0b1111 == 0b1000. The web address automatic download a gzip file which can be decompressed into a Json file.

```
    var routeFile: JsonRouteFile?
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let urlRoute:URL = URL(string: "http://data.taipei/bus/ROUTE")!

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let data:Data = try Data(contentsOf: urlRoute)
            routeFile = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonRouteFile?.self, from: data.decompress()!)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift works.
I didn't go through the enter installation though. Just dragged the file over.