# Xcode searching wrong Framework Search Path

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode is having trouble finding a particular file in my project, so I have added the path to the file in Build Settings - Search Paths - Framework Search Paths, however Xcode is not searching one of the folders.

The file in question is located at `Frameworks/aeroCommon/Zlib` in the parent directory of SRCROOT, so I am using ".." to search one level up from my project directory.

The search path I have specified in Framework Search Paths is:

`"$(SRCROOT)/../Frameworks/aeroCommon/ZLib"`

Using this path results in the following error:

`error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/user/Desktop/AppName/Frameworks/aeroCommon/zutil.c'`

It seems to be searching the Frameworks folder but does not go as far as to search the Zlib folder even though I specified it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your Frameworks folder under the Pods project?

Comment: Follow these steps will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648121/native-zlib-inflate-deflate-for-swift3-on-ios