# How do I import CommonCrypto in XCode 6.4?

Tags: swift, cryptography, xcode6.4

I'm relatively new to Swift and totally unfamiliar with Objective-C.

```
Import CommonCrypto
```

...does nothing. Is this implemented yet or do I have to do it in some old fashioned Objective-C header way?

I'm aware this question was asked a year ago during 6.0 beta, but this is about XCode 6.4. Not only that but if it's still in fact the same process, that process will have changed as the path has changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)

Comment: No it isn't. That was asked long ago during XCode 6 beta.

Comment: The process hasn't changed.

Comment: Actually the process will have to have changed as the path indicated in that answer has surely also changed. It's no longer beta 5.

Comment: Are you talking about using CommonCrypto in an *app* or in a *framework*? For an app, it should still work by adding `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` to the bridging header file.

Comment: I'm going to remove my answer below and re-write. Commenters are correct - my current answer isn't working.

Comment: Yeah and I followed the instructions with the old method of using the map and header file, that didn't work either. They've obviously changed something but never documented it anywhere that I can find.