# Xcode 7.3 beta 1 vs. CommonCrypto in Swift

Tags: frameworks, swift2, xcode7, commoncrypto

I'm using CommonCrypto in a Swift framework - and it's been working fine for over a year.

I used solutions found here: [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)

Specifically, to reference CommonCrypto from the Swift framework, I had to:

Create a `module.map` file in a folder named `CommonCrypto` next to my framework's Xcode project. `module.map` contents:

```
module CommonCrypto [system]
{
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
    link "CommonCrypto"
    export *
}
```

- In my framework project's Swift Import Paths, I add `CommonCrypto`
- In my framework project's Library Search Paths, I include:
  `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/system`
- In my source, I include: `import CommonCrypto`

This worked fine; a little convoluted - but it worked.

However, in Xcode 7.3 beta 1 (7D111g), this technique no longer works.

It appears that `libcommonCrypto.tbd` has been removed from: `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/system` inside Xcode-beta.app. And I can't find it anywhere under the iPhoneOS SDK folder structure.

So I get these errors:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/usr/lib/system'
>   ld: library not found for -lCommonCrypto for architecture arm64 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

It would be great if the crazy module map business was replaced with something simpler. Like for instance, just using `import CommonCrypto`

In any case, I'm not sure how to resolve this, so any help is appreciated.

I'm asking here as a new question in the event that the solution is substantially different from solutions found in the previous question, although I appreciate this may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to remove the line:

```
link "CommonCrypto"
```

from the module.map file.