# No such module 'CommonCrypto' error when testing umbrella app

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, commoncrypto

I've setup an application so that it uses a swift framework that contains a class that uses CommonCrypto utilities. Both the umbrella app and the swift framework have run their own tests independently. Dependencies are as follows:

```
MyApp <--------- MyAppTests
   |
   |
   *
MyFramework <--- FrameworkTests
   |
   |
   *
CommonCrypto
```

I've setup the CommonCrypto dependency using @stephencelis answer found in this other SO post: [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)

The following works without any problems:

- Building the Framework project
- Running tests on the Framework project
- Building the App
- Archiving the App
- Running the App

However, if I try to **Test** the app, I get the following error:
`No such module 'CommonCrypto'`, pointing me to the class in the Framework project that references CommonCrypto. Any Ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

P.S: Not sure how relevant this is but the app also has a AppleWatch extension.

Thanks!