# how to do data encryption in swift without using third party libraries?

Tags: ios, json, swift, security, encryption

I want to encrypt data on my app.while am google there is encryption allowed using Github libraries, is there any other ways available to do own programatically.

After Import Security framework, cannot able to get AES keywords.

Is there any tutorial available for encrypt data and send to server as json?

Comment: You can use the Secruity framework. You can see how here https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/blob/master/SwiftyRSA/SwiftyRSA.swift

Comment: is that framework is default from apple or third party? And i cannot able to find it on XCODE?

Comment: The security framework is from Apple

Comment: If you want AES then you need to use CommonCrypto but that is a bit tricky from Swift as it isn't a simple import;http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/03/using-commoncrypto-in-swift/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework