# Can I use an Objective-C class in my Swift framework library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have created a **Swift Framework** that I use in multiple projects. There is an Objectivce-C class that I would like to use in that is difficult to port in straight Swift. Lets say that class is SFTest

```
@interface SFTest {
} 
+ (NString *)myMethod(NSString *data);
@end
@implementation SFTest
+ (NString *)myMethod(NSString *data) {
    // does some processing
    return processedData;
}
@end
```

Can I somehow use this in my **Swift framework** project, and if yes, how? My research on this mentions something called bridging headers but that they can't be used in Swift frameworks.

Comment: I dont want to import CommonCrypto to use in Swift. I just want to use an Objective-C class in a Swift Framework. I can remove the common crypto in the code and use a simpler example.

Comment: Removed any mention of CommonCrypto so this should be much simpler to answer with a yes or no.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57682107/4770877

Answer (score 58, accepted):

So this took a while but I finally got something to run on my device. Here is my setup. I created a Swift Framework called swiftlib. I added an Objective-C class called "MyClass". Basically it looks like this:

[image]

I then modified the "umbrella header" to import my new Objective-C class. The umbrella header is the name of your swift library project. So in my case, it was "swiftlib.h". This is what is inside my umbrella header file:

```
//
//  swiftlib.h
//  swiftlib
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

//! Project version number for swiftlib.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double swiftlibVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for swiftlib.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char swiftlibVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your     framework using statements like #import <swiftlib/PublicHeader.h>
```

Make sure to set your header class to public or you will get a compile error. Basically whatever is included in the umbrella header is exposed to users of your swift framework so it needs to be public. Select MyClass.h and open the right details bar and select the dropdown here:

[image]

I then used this Swift framework in a single view application for testing and was able to use my Objective-C class in the AppDelegate.swift like so:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let test = MyClass.myMethod()
        print("test = " + String(test))
        return true
    }
```

This compiled and ran on my device.

For those curious, this was the implementation code for the Objective-C MyClass:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

@implementation MyClass

+ (NSString *)myMethod {
    NSString *key = @"test";
    NSString *data = @"mytestdata";
    const char *ckey = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cdata = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char chmac[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, ckey, strlen(ckey), cdata, strlen(cdata), chmac);
    NSData *hmac = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:chmac length:sizeof(chmac)];
    NSString *hash = [hmac base64Encoding];
    return hash;
}

@end
```

Comment: I havent tried but i hope this works with an ios app. What i am doing is i am using the framework inside another framework... it is giving clang error. Any help would be much appreciated.The first framework which contains objective c classes builds fine. but when i import it in another framework it builds with a clang error.

Comment: Not Succeed yet.  I have also try above solution but got error 
"Include of non-modular header inside framework module  in FrAmeworkNAme " Please help me out

Comment: @kailoon What if I don't want to expose this objective c file to the end user? Is it doable?

Comment: How about if I want to hide these header files from the end user? I just want my framework to internally use these objective-c files.

Comment: @SazidIqabal I forgot to make the header public thats why I was getting this error.

Comment: @DareDevil I am getting the same error Include of non-modular header inside framework module in, My header file is marked public even then I see this error. How did you fix this ?

Comment: I just got rid of the objc classes to solve this for now, Keeping it simple.

Comment: @Max: You can goto Framework -> Target -> Build Phases and drag to move the relevant header files from Project to Public.

Answer (score -10):

First use objective c class in your swift project you have to create  bridging header file in that file you have to import objective c class and then you can use that class in swift

Comment: Bridging header don't work with frameworks its application to app projects.