# How to use Objective C bridging header in swift framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, objc-bridging-header

I have created my own cocoa POD framework in swift, which uses `#import CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h` in Objective C bridging header file, but when I try to use same POD in project, It gives compile error -

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module '': 
>   '/Users/macmini/Downloads/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h'"

Please let me know how I can fix the same.

I am using this for creating my own POD framework in swift.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Target -> Build Settings -> search for "Modules" ->
Set "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" to Yes.

This will allow you to use Objective C bridging header file in your project.

Comment: Adding "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" to YES, does not work. Still getting same error

Comment: Then you should try "@import CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h;" instead of "#import CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h" as both are potential workarounds but both breakdown under some cases. Converting to `@import` ceases to work if there are transitive dependencies.