# Creating a fat framework with an objective c framework dependency

Tags: objective-c, swift, alamofire, moya, dynamic-frameworks

I am working with Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1. I am trying to build a framework in Swift that depends on Alamofire which is written in Objective C. I added the Alamofire.xcodeproj manually as given in the README by Alamofire. The individual target builds fine. My Framework target builds fine.

The problem arises when I try to create a fat framework using a script that uses the following command

```
xcodebuild -project "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcodeproj" -scheme "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=no BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos" -derivedDataPath "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
```

I get the following error:

> umbrella header 'Alamofire.h' not found
>
> could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire'

The second line of the error is coming from another dependency 'Moya' that depends on Alamofire (See Image)
[image]

It's puzzling that normal Cmd+B works fine for usual target but xcodebuild fails.

Things that I attempted:

1. Deleting Derived folder, Clean Build.
2. Building individual dependencies first and then build the Universal Aggregated Target.
3. [Creating a custom module map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)
4. Changing configurations of all dependencies to same e.g. Debug
5. Changing Swift Language Version of Alamofire.xcodeproj to be Swift 4.2

I think xcodebuild command needs more input. What am I missing?

**Updates:**

I dig in further. The Headers folder [image]
inside Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework/ is empty which it is expected to contain umbrella header Alamofire.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the nested dependency was an issue.

MyFramework had dependency on Moya and Moya had dependency on Alamofire. After I added Alamofire.xcodeproj as submodule to Moya.xcodeproj, xcodebuild magically found all umbrella headers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried any of these :

1.Adding -ObjC in Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags.

2.Importing all the frameworks that the Objective C framework depends on into your project i.e;in Build Phases --> Link Binary With Libraries .

3.Adding #import's for those to a prefix header file, which must be added to your project in build settings in the Prefix Header field.

**Update :**
Elaborating point 3 :

To use Objective C Framework in your Swift project you have to create a Swift Bridging Header file in that project. The best way is to create the .h file Manually.

First, add a header file to your project with the name: MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h. This will be the single header file where you import any Objective C code you need your Swift code to have access.

Find Swift Compiler - Code Generation section in your project build settings. Add the path to your bridging header file next to Objective C Bridging Header from the project root folder. It should be MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h

It just needs a single Bridging Header. Enter #import statements to this file and your classes will be available in your Swift project code without any additional #import statements.

[image: build settings]

You can also have a look at this tutorial :
[Integrating objective c in swift](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-objective-c-file-swift)

Comment: 1 and 2 are checked already. What about third one? I don't see an option to add a Prefix Header field.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pooja. I am using Xcode 10.1 and settings look a bit different over there.