# Bridging file on Swift framework

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm creating a Swift framework and I need to use SQLite, when I create a bridging file the compiler gives me the following error: `using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`, however I found this project (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) which includes a bridging file. How has he done it?

Comment: You should create bridging file using this link.Pls make sure your Objective-c File include in bridging class and Bridging file are set in your target. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift.

Comment: My case is in a framework not on a app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a bridging file within a framework. The solution is to use a map file. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25422889/4365754