# Add SQLite framework to my project

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sqlite

I am using xcode8 + swift3.1. My project is targeting iOS 8.0.

I would like to use SQLite framework directly without using 3rd party wrapper.

When I do:

```
import SQLite
```

I got compiler error that `no such module 'SQLite'`. Then, I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065880/swift-cant-import-sqlite3-ios) for xcode8.1+Swift3 with following steps:

1. I go to project's Build Phases
2. I search for **SQLite** framework in "Link Binary With Libraries"

here, when I search for SQLite, I got:

[image]

As you can see, I got `libsqlite3.tbd`, **under iOS 10.3 folder**.

**My question is,** does it mean user with iOS prior to 10.3 not able to use my app because I am using iOS 10.3 SQLite framework? Does the folder name `iOS 10.3` hint that?

(My project target is iOS 8.0)

Comment: Sorry, just a comment and question passing through: Is it okay to use sqlite in iOS? I've been believing that here are only two kinds of databases or two kinds of persistence frameworks for iOS: Core Data and Realm. I know Core Data uses Sqlite though.

Comment: @Glenn, I believe it is possible, but I just started to use it as you can see from my question:)

Comment: I see. Why use it though? :D Anyways, I hope you get some answers soon.

Comment: @Glenn, because I want to create my own lightweight wrapper. :)

Comment: @Glenn I've been using SQLite in my iOS apps since 2009. It's fully supported.

Comment: `import SQLite3` works only in  Xcode 9. In Xcode 8 and earlier you have to `#import <sqlite3.h>` in the bridging header file and add the library "manually". – See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642293/1187415 for full instructions. (It only depends on Xcode, not on the iOS deployment target.)

Comment: Wow awesome guys.